# Where do I put H2 trigger class?

Tags: java, triggers, classpath, h2

I create a class file which is extend Trigger. Also I create trigger query. But when i run this trigger I get class not found error. On the documentation it is mentioned that put custom trigger class to database class path? what does exactly means class path? Do i need recompile h2?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your class is compiled/packed to filename **trigger.jar**.
If you use **h2.bat/h2.sh** to run h2 db in server mode, put
**trigger.jar** into this command:

```
@java -cp "h2-1.4.196.jar;trigger.jar;%H2DRIVERS%;%CLASSPATH%" org.h2.tools.Console %*
```