# How do I get H2 database trigger to work in server mode?

Tags: database, triggers, h2

I am an inexperienced H2 Trigger developer... So lets get that out of the way (ie I am dumb)... Plus, I am reluctant to even ask questions here since it seems that there is an abundance of mean people.

What I am trying to do:
Create a Trigger for updates to a row on one table (ie TEST) and log the original row to another table (ie TEST_hist).  Additionally, there is some logic if the update is a "delete", then I log the delete with the user name to the history table.  I realize what I have done here probably is not good style, but it is just a test and I don't believe that has anything to do with the problem that I am experiencing.

What I have done:

1. Create a trigger named TriggerTest defined as follows:

   package com.test;

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Timestamp;

   import org.h2.api.Trigger;

   public class TriggerTest implements Trigger {

   ```
    @Override
    public void init(Connection conn, String schemaName, String triggerName, String tableName, boolean before, int type)
            throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void fire(Connection conn, Object[] oldRow, Object[] newRow) throws SQLException {

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // NOTE: Copy the old row into the history table
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO TEST_hist (testKey, MAINT_ACTION, MAINT_DATE_TIME, MAINT_USER) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")
            ) {
                stmt.setLong(1, (Long)oldRow[0]);
                stmt.setString(2, (String)oldRow[1]);
                stmt.setTimestamp(3, (Timestamp)oldRow[2]);
                stmt.setString(4, (String)oldRow[3]);

                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // NOTE: If the operation is a delete, then create a new entry for it
        //       in the history table too.
        if (((String)newRow[newRow.length-4]).equals("delete")) {
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO TEST_hist (testKey, MAINT_ACTION, MAINT_DATE_TIME, MAINT_USER) " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")
                ) {
                    stmt.setLong(1, (Long)newRow[0]);
                    stmt.setString(2, (String)newRow[1]);
                    stmt.setTimestamp(3, (Timestamp)newRow[2]);
                    stmt.setString(4, (String)newRow[3]);

                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                }

            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "DELETE FROM TEST " +
                    "WHERE id=?")
                ) {
                    stmt.setLong(1, (Long)oldRow[0]);
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void remove() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static Trigger create() {
        return new TriggerTest();
    }
   ```

   }
2. Compiled my test trigger into a JAR file named Trigger.jar
3. Start H2 database in server mode making sure to include my new jar file in the classpath (ie `java -cp Trigger.jar -jar h2-1.4.200.jar -webAllowOthers -tcpAllowOthers`)
4. As a result of starting H2 in server mode, the console app is started in the browser.
   After I log into the console, I create tables named TEST and TEST_hist defined as follows

   CREATE TABLE TEST (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
   MAINT_ACTION ENUM('insert','update','delete'),
   MAINT_DATE_TIME Timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
   MAINT_USER VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
   );

   CREATE TABLE TEST_hist (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
   testKey INT NOT NULL,
   MAINT_ACTION ENUM('insert','update','delete'),
   MAINT_DATE_TIME Timestamp NOT NULL,
   MAINT_USER VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
   );
5. Create the Trigger in the console as follows:

   CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_TEST
   AFTER UPDATE
   ON TEST
   FOR EACH ROW
   CALL "com.test.TriggerTest"
6. When I run that command, I get the following error in the console window:
   Error creating or initializing trigger "UPDATE_TEST" object, class "com.test.TriggerTest", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Class ""com.test.TriggerTest"" not found [90086-200]"; see root cause for details; SQL statement:
   CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_TEST
   AFTER UPDATE
   ON TEST
   FOR EACH ROW
   CALL "com.test.TriggerTest" [90043-200] 90043/90043 (Help)

So, I know the problem is that it can't find my class... But, I don't know why... I thought I was doing the right things by doing the steps above (ie adding my jar file to the classpath of the H2 server)

Where I have looked for answers:
Everywhere on stackoverflow where answers seemed somewhat relevant, but didn't quite answer my question -- the following were the closest things I could find...

- [H2 Trigger doesn't Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909318/h2-trigger-doesnt-trigger)
- [Where do I put H2 trigger class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070664/where-do-i-put-h2-trigger-class)

Plus, I looked at H2's site...
https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_trigger

Please help and tia.

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes after CALL? I see double quotes in your snippet, this is a potential issue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried it with single quotes and it gives a "Syntax error in SQL statement [...]" when I do use single quotes.